How to send an email, with attachment, using rust and google_gmail1
Goal
I have a service account XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com, I already activated GmailAPI in gcp.
The service account role is owner, and I've already use it to interact with google_drive2 and google_sheets4 successfully.
And I want to send an email with an file attachment using rust library google_gmail1.
let secret : ServiceAccountKey = /* read from json */;
let hub    : Gmail<_>          = /* create from secret */;

let to        : String = /* email address */;
let subject   : String = /* ... */;
let content   : String = /* ... */;
let file_name : String = /* ... */;
let file      : File   = std::fs::File::open(file_name).unwrap();

let header : Vec<MessagePartHeader> = vec![
    MessagePartHeader{ Some("To".to_string())      , Some(to)      },
    MessagePartHeader{ Some("Subject".to_string()) , Some(subject) },
];

Trial
To to that I first tried the example on docs.rs, try to get some sense of how to do it.
set up a file.ext with some text content and run.
let mut req = Message::default();
 
let result = hub
    .users()
    .messages_send(req, to)
    .upload_resumable(fs::File::open("file.ext").unwrap(), "application/octet-stream".parse().unwrap())
    .await;

return Error::Failure, withbody
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported. ",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported. ",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

and I don't know how to continue.
I've also tried uploading different mime format text/plain, text/csv and text/* all return the same error message saying format not supported
Question
How to achieve the goal?

where does the attached file content goes? In the Message struct, or the file argument in upload_resumable()?
How to construct from all the component I have i.e. header, content and file, filename?


Have you configured domain wide delegation on the service account?

The role of the service account is owner, and I already use the same service account to interact with google_drive3 and google_sheets4 succefully, so I think the IAM is no issue

If your file is plain text, you should probably use the text/plain MIME type instead of application/octet-stream

I've tried using mime format text/plain, text/csv and text/* all return the same error message saying format not supported.

Service accounts only work with gmail if you have configured Domain wide deligation in your google workspace account and send the subject domain user which you would like to delegate as in your code.   It has nothing to do with weather or not they are owner or if it works with google drive and sheets these are different apis with diffrent requirements.   I just want to ensure your not wasting your time trying to use Gmail with a service account on a standard gmail user.   This comment is 100% not related to your issue.

Oh that's exactly what I did, I didn't know that it's not possible. Thank you very much.
